# How to fill date picked with selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried to create an account on instagram using selenium, the first page was without problem, but after the "creating an account" there is a page with birthdate. 
I have this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("h144Z  ").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='1']").send_keys("5")
```

It clicks the month, but doesnt choose one.
Any idea how to pick month, day and year? (btw the class name "h144Z  " is same in every picker)

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://www.swtestacademy.com/datepicker-using-selenium/

Comment: nope, I didnt find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Dont do

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("h144Z  ").click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='1']").send_keys("5")
```

do

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("h144Z  ").send_keys("5")
```

But still idk, how to fill the other ones with same class name.

Answer (score 0):

Using select class 
Option 1

```
 s1= Select(find_element_by_xpath(//*[contains(@title,'Month')]
 s1.select_by_value('5')
```

Option 2

```
 s1= Select(find_element_by_xpath(//*[contains(@title,'Month')]
 s1.select_by_index('5')
```

Option 3

```
 s1= Select(find_element_by_xpath(//*[contains(@title,'Month')]
 s1.select_by_visible_text('May')
```

Comment: yeah, but I dont have instagram in english, so it wouldnt work

Comment: change xpath from tittle to class ,'h144Z'  i think it should work.